# Syntax for user defined composite type literal

Tags: sql, postgresql, user-defined-types

I have some UDTs (user defined types) in my code (PostgreSQL 9.2)

```
create type pairs_t as (keyname varchar, e_value varchar);
create type values_t as (e_values varchar[]);
create type allvalues_t as (regions values_t, products pairs_t);
```

and used as in:

```
create or replace function foo( IN _x allvalues_t[] ) returns void as $$ begin...
```

The actual UDTs in application are more complex.

But I cannot figure out how to type up a test case. E.g., if I wanted `(a,prod-a),(b,prod-b)` for products and () for regions, how would a `SELECT * from foo(...)` statement in pgAdmin SQL window look like? What should `...` be?

I would appreciate if someone could post a guide or a page that describes this syntax. I have looked at postgresql man pages but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [**`CREATE TYPE`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtype.html) in the manual.

Your example defines the type `allvalues_t`, but later uses `allvalues`. Also `values_t` -> `value_t`. Looks like a simple typos.  You can't be that sloppy if you want to get it right.

Syntax of for  composite could be type:

```
SELECT * from foo(('{"(\"(\"\"{arr_a,arr_b}\"\")\",\"(foo,bar)\")","(\"(\"\"{arr_a,arr_b}\"\")\",\"(foo,bar)\")"}'))
```

How can you find out yourself?

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE pairs_t (keyname varchar, e_value varchar);
-- OR CREATE TYPE for a more permanent solution. 
INSERT INTO pairs_t VALUES ('foo', 'bar');

CREATE TEMP TABLE values_t (e_values varchar[]);
INSERT INTO values_t VALUES ('{arr_a, arr_b}');


CREATE TEMP TABLE allvalues_t (regions values_t, products pairs_t);
INSERT INTO allvalues_t VALUES((SELECT x FROM values_t x), (SELECT x FROM pairs_t x));

CREATE TEMP TABLE test (t allvalues_t[]);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (ARRAY[(SELECT x FROM allvalues_t x), (SELECT x FROM allvalues_t x)]);

SELECT * FROM test
SELECT x FROM allvalues_t x;
```